# Dividing 2 numbers in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing SQL Server query calculations and the division always gives me zero.

```
SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED) 
, SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED)
, SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED) / SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED) AS 'Percent'
```

The sample dataset returned is:

[image]

In this example, the third row should have a division value of 1.02, but it's shown as zero. Why is that?

Comment: Note that none of the pairs of values could give you 1.02 as a result of the division, because in every pair the dividend is less than the divisor. (Based on your code, the second value is divided by the first one, but you seem to have verified your results the other way round.)

Comment: Yes oops my bad..... you are correct! :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try

```
SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED) * 1.0 / SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED)
```

An integer devision can only return full numbers and not floating point numbers. You can force a floating point division like in the example above.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED) 
, SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED)
, SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED)*1.0 / SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED)
```

Answer (score 2):

The two problems are that you

1. perform an integer division (`SUM` returns an integer), and
2. you swapped the dividend and the divisor (that's why you get zero instead of one).

This is how you could fix it (note that `LINES_ORDERED` and `LINES_CONFIRMED` are swapped):

```
SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED) 
, SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED)
, (1.0*SUM(sl.LINES_ORDERED)) / SUM(sl.LINES_CONFIRMED) AS 'Percent'
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be because you're divinding two integers.

Convert the two values in the division to decimals first:

```
, SUM(convert(decimal(12,2),sl.LINES_CONFIRMED)) 
/ SUM(convert(decimal(12,2),sl.LINES_ORDERED)) AS 'Percent'
```