# CAST as decimal, or *1.0?

Tags: sql-server, casting

Both of the following queries will give me the same result, and I've seen both techniques being used in the past to ensure a `decimal` data type is returned.

```
select CAST(5 as decimal(18,2))/2

select 5*1.0/2
```

Which method is best to use?

Why would people use `*1.0` over casting? Is this just because its quicker to type?

Comment: I think you got the query because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985196/dividing-2-numbers-in-sql-server)

Comment: @hims056 I did see use of `*1.0` in that answer, but nothing explaining why `*1.0` is being used over casting, and I've seen both techniques used in the past before. However I'm more interested in which technique is better practice so that going forward I can use the best method

Comment: The methods don't in fact return precisely the same result. The first one returns a `decimal(22, 6)` and the second a `decimal(9, 6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control the precision or scale of the result, then you'll have to use `CAST` or `CONVERT`. But I believe that if you just want "a decimal", then as you suggested, it's just quicker to type `* 1.0`.

Comment: @Curt - I'd be remarkably surprised if there was. On a very quick crude test, converting ~2000 numbers, they performed equally well.