# Divide TIME(0) data type by INT data type and produce SUM in seperate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `TimeLog`and columns `StartTime`, `FinishTime`, `Units`, `ElapsedTime`. I want to take `ElapsedTime` and divide by `Units` to produce a UPH column. This is what I have thus far...

```
SELECT StartTime, 
  FinishTime, 
  ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0)), 
  Units 
FROM TimeLog

StartTime   FinishTime  ElapsedTime Units
08:00:00    08:25:00    00:25:00    0
08:25:00    09:15:00    00:50:00    0
09:55:00    12:32:00    02:37:00    55
12:32:00    14:31:00    01:59:00    23
12:32:00    13:55:00    01:23:00    55
```

Would like to see results as

```
StartTime    FinishTime  ElapsedTime Units  UPH
08:00:00     08:25:00    0:25:00 0  (ElapsedTime/Units)
08:25:00     09:15:00    0:50:00 0  (ElapsedTime/Units)
09:55:00     12:32:00    2:37:00 55 (ElapsedTime/Units)
12:32:00     14:31:00    1:59:00 23 (ElapsedTime/Units)
12:32:00     13:55:00    1:23:00 55 (ElapsedTime/Units)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dividing 2 numbers in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985196/dividing-2-numbers-in-sql-server)

Comment: You need to specify the prevision. For example, looking at the 4th row... that's ALMOST 12 an hour... or maybe it actually is 12 an hour. If you want this precise, our may want to determine the units per minute and aggregate up. This will leave you something like 12.33 units per hour versus 12 units per hour. Anyway, specify the precision by showing what your expected output should be :)

Comment: @scsimon Hey there, im kind of new to stackoverflow. I have edited my question to reflect what I am trying to achieve the best I could :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NULLIF to change the 0 Units to NULL.
Dividing by NULL gives NULL, thus it avoids the `Divide by zero error encountered` error.

Multiplying by the float 1.0 to change the INT you get from the datediff to a float.

And using ISNULL to change the NULL's to 0.

Then casting it all to a decimal, which implicitly rounds it.

```sql
-- Using a table variable for the test
declare @TimeLog table (StartTime TIME, FinishTime TIME, Units int);
insert into @TimeLog (StartTime, FinishTime, Units) values
('08:00:00','09:00:00',60),
('08:00:00','10:00:00',60),
('08:00:00','08:25:00',0),
('08:25:00','09:15:00',0),
('09:55:00','12:32:00',55),
('12:32:00','14:31:00',23),
('12:32:00','13:55:00',55);

SELECT 
  StartTime, FinishTime, 
  ElapsedTime = convert(time,dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0)),
  Units,

  AverageUnitsPerMinute = cast(isnull(Units / nullif(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime)*1.0,0),0.0) as decimal(10,4)),

  AverageHoursPerUnit = cast(isnull(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)/nullif(Units,0),0)/3600.0 as decimal(10,4)),
  AverageMinutesPerUnit = cast(isnull(datediff(millisecond,StartTime,FinishTime)/nullif(Units,0),0)/60000.0 as decimal(10,2))
FROM @TimeLog;
```

For the AverageHoursPerUnit:
Dividing the seconds by 3600.0 (60 minutes*60 seconds) to get the hours.

Comment: Hey thanks, looks good. Question, this is producing a per minute SUM correct? How can we show the number of Units per hour as UPH

Comment: I thinh you should cast the numerator to decimal, not the final fraction. For example `SELECT CAST(10/60 AS decimal(10,2))` should RETURN 0, but `SELECT CAST(10 AS decimal(10,2))/60` returns 0.166666

Comment: @TriV Hi can you show your example in a complete query based off my table and column names please?

Comment: @DRUIDRUID Ah, so that UPH is per hour. Updated.

Comment: @TriV That's why I divide by the float 3600.0

Comment: @LukStorms Hi, sorry I should have explained that, UPH (Units Per Hour) I like how you added the AverageMinutes PerUnit, can you change that to show AverageUnitsPerMinute? Also on the UPH column, I see that the result is really low number based off the Units, should it be higher? Or is this showing minutes per unit?

Comment: StartTime FinishTime ElapsedTime Units UPH AverageMinutesPerUnit
    8:55:00 9:23:00 0:28:00 33 0.0139 0.85
    7:00:00 10:30:00 3:30:00 415 0.0083 0.51
    8:55:00 9:23:00 0:28:00 33 0.0139 0.85
    8:55:00 9:23:00 0:28:00 22 0.0211 1.27
    8:55:00 9:23:00 0:28:00 11 0.0422 2.55

Comment: @DRUIDRUID I've added an AverageUnitsPerMinute this time. Along with some test data.